# How do I mark duplicate values from one field in another field

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to write an "X" in a field if the value from another field is a duplicate?
One of the duplicates should not be marked with an "X".

[image]

I have searched the internet but could not find a similar case and I have no idea where to start with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a join approach here:

```sql
SELECT t1.Id, t1.DATA, IIF(ISNULL(t2.DATA), 'x', '') AS DUPLICATE
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT DATA, MIN(Id) AS MinId
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY DATA
) t2
    ON t2.DATA = t1.DATA AND
       t2.MinId = t1.Id
```

Comment: For `SELECT`ing that will work fine. However, you can't write this to another field as the OP asked, since a join with an aggregate makes it non-updateable.

Answer (score 2):

You could do so with an update query that identifies duplicates, by using an `EXISTS` clause to check if an identical record exists with a lesser ID:

```
UPDATE SomeTable m
SET Duplicate = "x"
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SomeTable s WHERE m.DATA = s.DATA and m.Id > s.Id)
```

Comment: I suggest _not_ doing an update here, as then the OP will have to re-run the update every time data changes, new data is added, deleted, etc.  Instead, a view/query approach seems like a better option to me.

Comment: Well, OP explicitly asked for writing to a field, which is done with an `UPDATE`. If you think that's a bad idea, that's best addressed under the question, not an answer providing what's asked